# Quality of soil in plants sold in 6" pots sold at retail stores?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care

Should I transplant plants (herbs mainly) in 6" pots that I buy at megastores like the Home Depot? It seems the soil's spongy; it doesn't even feel like soil. The plants aren't dead (or at least not yet) and I water them on a regular basis.

The plants are on an open balcony with a roof, so they don't receive direct sun.

Thanks.

Comment: I buy all my plants from a local supermarket because I can't easily access a specialty store. I find that the soil isn't an issue, but the plants are usually root bound, so try to repot them when you bring them home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not initially, no, it's not necessary, but within a short space of time during the growing season, you'll find they need bigger pots anyway as they grow because they'll need more root room, so do it then. How quickly they'll need potting on to something larger varies a bit between varieties of plant, so a rosemary, for instance, will need to go in something bigger quite quickly, but thyme not so rapidly. If they're already rootbound (turn them out of their pots to check) then pot on into larger containers immediately.

Comment: Thanks. When they start outgrowing the pots, I'll naturally move them to bigger pots. I just thought that the soil included in the pots was possibly inferior since it doesn't feel anything like the soil I purchased.

Comment: Well certainly what they grow them in doesn't supply optimum conditions over time, but it's not so bad its going to stop them growing properly - it'll get them through very well until they need planting out or a bigger pot.

Comment: The cheapest potting soil is usually just fine.  The more expensive stuff with water holding gels or fertilizer or lots of vermiculite are the worst.  Fertilizer should not be applied right away as plants to be sold in the stores are usually newly fertilized.  Drainage, no rocks at the bottom of pot, do not water until the soil is dry and/or the plant shows need of water, no sitting in water in the saucer.

Answer (score 1):

These plants are grown commercially in large quantities. Obviously the growers want their plants to grow well and look good (otherwise people wouldn't buy them!) but it's a reasonable bet that the growing medium will (1) be the cheapest that is available in bulk in the country where they were grown (not necessarily the country where you bought them!) and (2) it will be "designed" to be used with an automatic watering system, not hand watering.

A potting compost that is "spongy" and doesn't "feel like soil" probably isn't soil. For example it may be coir (coconut fibre) which is a good growing material, and an environmentally friendly way of using what would otherwise be just waste material.

If you want to keep the plants in the same pots for a long time, don't forget to feed them as well as watering them. Commercial growers are not going to give you a "free" long-term supply of slow-release fertilizer added to their compost. They are more likely to add (very dilute) liquid feed continuously to their automatic watering system, to give the plants just as much as they actually need while keeping their costs to a minimum.

Feeding may be a problem if you don't know what the growing material is, because different materials have different requirements to supplement the nutrients (if any) that the material itself contains. So repotting the plants may be the simplest way to keep them in growing well in the long term.